# Returning a JTextField to editing after a warning dialog

Tags: java, focus, jtextfield

In my application I have a JTextField that will only allow the user to fill it with input formatted in a certain way.  I have a method that checks if input into the field is valid and if not it displays a dialog.  After this occurs I would like the focus to return to the text field so that the user can correct there mistake and type in the appropriately formatted input.  I tried to do this by having the JTextField call requestFocus() on itself but this seems to only half work.  The JTextField displays the flashing cursor but I cannot actually type in any text until I click on the text field again.  Is there another method I need to call?  I could not find anything else in the documentation.

Comment: In the API it says "use of this method is discouraged because its behavior is platform dependent. Instead we recommend the use of `requestFocusInWindow()`". Did you tried this one ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not exactly the solution you asked for, but you might want to look at javax.swing.InputVerifier. This object allows you to verify the input to a field and prevent taking focus away from it if the format isn't right. I don't think it would allow you to put up a dialog explaining the error (though it might - try it) but it would certainly allow you to put a message in a 'message area'.

What you do is set an InputVerifier on the JComponent, have it test the contents for validity; if it isn't right then the JComponent won't release focus (and can write an error message).